# ASP.NET MVC4 with Two-Factor and Blind Hashing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-membership

ASP.NET newbie here, I'm looking for a way to integrate my existing database into ASP.NET's authentication system. I have a separate project making use of Entity Framework to interact with a database (Model-First Entity Framework 5) that I would like my ASP.NET MVC 4 site to use to authenticate off.

To further complicate matters, this is not a simple username/hash/salt table. I employ [Blind Hashing](http://www.opine.me/a-better-way-to-store-password-hashes/) and two factor authentication using the Google Authenticator (OATH-TOTP) is an option users can have. Additionally, I don't just have users, I have Accounts and Profiles, of which an Account can have many profiles (distinct, separate 'users' in a public sense that the owner can easily switch between). Lastly, Account can also have several emails, not just one. In other words, this doesn't fit in to normal user/password conventions when dealing with authentication. Fortunately, I've written partial classes to give most of these entities (such as Account) ways to handle this easily, such as:

`someAccount.CheckPassword(password[, twoFactorToken])`

I can do this easily enough using Entity Framework 5, but I'm very unfamiliar with how ASP.NET MVC 4 handles users. Is there an easy way to get user authentication going in ASP.NET MVC 4? Do I need to do something with MembershipProvider? Do I use SimpleMembership or the legacy one? Bonus: Can I take advantage of Windows Identity Framework and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've opted instead not to use the Membership Provider, and just use Forms Authentication. I did not realize you could use this without using a membership provider.